# Git breaks merge commit, if won't push it and execute pull with rebase option

Tags: git, merge, push, rebase, pull

Sometimes things that I don't want to happen, happens with my repository. Here is one of scenarios that I want to avoid but don't know the best approach:

```
git init --bare bare.git;
git clone bare.git/ clonned1;
git clone bare.git/ clonned2;
cd clonned1;
REV=1;echo "$REV commit" > $REV.file;git add .;git ci -m "$REV commit";
REV=2;echo "$REV commit" > $REV.file;git add .;git ci -m "$REV commit";
git push;
git co -b new-branch;
REV=3;echo "$REV commit" > $REV.file;git add .;git ci -m "$REV commit";
REV=4;echo "$REV commit" > $REV.file;git add .;git ci -m "$REV commit";
git push -u origin new-branch;
gitk --all;
```

Repository state:

[image]

```
git co master;
git merge --no-ff new-branch;
gitk --all;
```

Repository state:

[image]

```
cd ../clonned2;
git pull;
REV=5;echo "$REV commit" > $REV.file;git add .;git ci -m "$REV commit";
REV=6;echo "$REV commit" > $REV.file;git add .;git ci -m "$REV commit";
git push;
gitk --all;
```

Repository state:

[image]

```
cd ../clonned1;
git pull --rebase;
gitk --all;
```

Repository state:

[image]

As you can see I lose my merge commit on master branch, it means I lose a part of a project history. Of course, stupid me, I forgot to push my changes. But it happens from time to time.

How to avoid this? How to be sure that I don't forget to push? Is there any way that git will tell me about this? Maybe my approach is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I tend to fall back to using `git reset` on the master of `clonned1`, after fetching the latest content:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard @{u}
git merge new-branch
```

The first command fetches all the remote data.  The second one resets master to be the same as the remote, and drops your commits from master.  The final one redoes the merge.

In general, anything involving rebase and a merge is suspect as rebase drops merge commits.  Even the `git rebase -p` option--which is supposed to preserve merges--fails here because it rebases the commits on the branch along with it, leaving graph looking like this:

[image]

So the best bet is to redo the merge as I've described above.

One thing I do to help me avoid this problem is to put some information in my prompt.  In particular, when there is an upstream set, I use `git rev-list --count --right-only @{u}...` to tell me how far ahead master is in front of the remote.  That ends up showing up as a number in my prompt, and serves as a reminder to push the new revisions up.